# How to clear memcached for multiple servers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.1, memcached, dalli

My Rails app is sharing two servers, one for users and the other for admin. I have added dalli-memcached for user interface and cache gets expires if it updates anything, which is working fine.

But I want to clear the cache from the admin server also.

So I have added

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, 'app_url',
```

in environment file, but getting error

```
DalliError: No server available
```

This means I am giving the wrong address. Which address do I need to give? App_url or ip_address?

Have tried with both but getting same error.

If anyone knowa od any other method to expire user-server cache please let me know.

Comment: Second argument is supposed to be memcache instance host/IP, not sure what do you mean by `app_url`?

Comment: i tried with application url i.e. http://example.com and also with ip but both didnt work

Comment: If you try `telnet MEMCACHEDIP 11211` where MEMCACHEDIP is address where your memcached is running what response do you get?

Comment: You have to run this from console/terminal, not Rails, of course.

Comment: telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused. But if i tries this with different port its working fine.

Comment: Yes, but memcached runs on that port by default. 90% chance that your memcache is not running. I would advise to head to SuperUser and ask for help how to properly set up memcached depending on your system.

Comment: I have user dalli gem. It automatically does all setup, isn't it? If not can you please tell me the setup steps?